# How can I call the phone number given in the edittext with the help of a button in android studio?

Tags: java, android, button

I need to call the given phone number which I had specified in the `edittext`. But when I press the call button after entering the number, there is no response.

I need to launch the caller window directly from my app as soon as I press my call button after entering the number in the `edittext`. Please help me, friends. And also let me know what's wrong in my code.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Here's my coding

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button mDialButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dial);

        mDialButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callNumber();
            }
        });
    }

    private String getPhoneNumber() {
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        return number.getText().toString();

    }

    private void callNumber() {
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getPhoneNumber()));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        startActivity(call);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="arun.com.phonecall">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't requested the permissions. If you don't have permissions already, you need to request them instead of returning directly.

You can use my library to handle runtime permissions easily. Check https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is about the permission because (from your code) you haven't correctly asked the permission for the `ACTION_CALL` read more for asking the permission at [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

You can use `ACTION_DIAL` if you don't want to have a business with the permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, 
                       Uri.fromParts("tel", getPhoneNumber(), null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText number;
int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button mDialButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dial);

    mDialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callNumber();
        }
    });
}

private String getPhoneNumber() {
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
    return number.getText().toString();

}

private void callNumber() {
    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getPhoneNumber()));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && checkSelfPermission(
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        requestPermissions(
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(call);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1000:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getPhoneNumber()));
                startActivity(call);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission is denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

    }

}



}
```

Comment: @reshma-dhaduk, please add some explanations to your answer. It will help other users.

Comment: @Da1 please accept Reshma's answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            call .setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +  getPhoneNumber()));
            call .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivity(call);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check run time permission for `Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE` and then you can call like this

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getPhoneNumber()));
      startActivity(intent);
```